# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: asp.net, sql

i am having a grid view and when i click page 2 the error given was highlighted at my sql command which is this : `SqlCommand cmdShow = new SqlCommand("delete from Student where NRIC= '" + GridView1.DataKeys[0].Value + "'", conn);` and state that the error was : `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index`

thsi is my code :

```
  protected void GridView1_RowDeleted(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MCDU\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=n;Integrated Security=True");

        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmdShow = new SqlCommand("delete from Student where NRIC= '" + GridView1.DataKeys[0].Value + "'", conn);

        cmdShow.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();

        Response.Redirect("studentParticulars.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: hi, i got 2 question, is your page 2 contain any items? is this happened during page 2 page load ?

Comment: i have 100 plus data in my database i put it 15 per data per page. but once i click on page 2 it will prompt me this error. yeah happen on page 2 load.

Comment: in this case, u need to show your paging code =)

Comment: i dun have paging code. i jus allow paging like this :  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" 
                        onrowcommand="GridView1_RowDeleted"
                        BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="50px" Width="487px" 
                        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" BorderStyle="None" PageSize="15">

Comment: What you are trying is that Clicking the delete button will delete that row ? Is this why you used: AutoGenerateDeleteButton .

Comment: yup.. to deleted the entire row.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `GridView1.DataKeys` is not epty. This error can only be caused by `GridView1.DataKeys[0]` operator on the line.

Answer (score 1):

There are zero items in the `GridView1.DataKeys` collection.

That error message is means that you attempted to access outside the bounds of an array collection.  There only place where it appears you are indexing into an array or collection is on `GridView1.DataKeys`

Comment: what should i put in the datakeys instead of 0 . sorry i am quite new with all this..

Comment: `GridViewCommandEventArgs` contains the row indexes of the rows and the key values that were deleted.  Use these values.  The RowDeleted event occurs after the rows have been removed from the GridView, so the GridView can be empty when you ask for a row - which gives you the exception.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewdeletedeventargs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

So, As you confirmed that when you click on `delete` button, row should be deleted. From what you have in your GridView Markup, Please make below corrections:

Since you are using SqlDataSource as the DataSourceID for your GridView, This SqldataSource control will take care of delete functionality. This is because when we click delete button the GridView will accordingly pass on this to `SqlDataSource` with correct parameters.  Simply set the `Delete` command of this DataSource control as:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthWindEntities %>"  
SelectCommand="Select top 20 ContactName,CompanyName,CustomerID from Customers" 
DeleteCommand="Delete from Customers where CustomerID=@CustomerID" 
UpdateCommand="UPDATE Customers SET ContactName = ContactName,
CompanyName=@CompanyName WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID" >
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now, you also need to correct your GridView markup, since you require that Delete button will delete a row and you have assigned the `GridView1_RowDeleted`  function as a event handler to `onrowcommand` which really doesn't makes any sense. Your GridView markup should be like : [ No `onrowcommand`. Keep the `AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true"` ]

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC"
BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="50px"
Width="487px" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" BorderStyle="None" PageSize="15">
```

Now, just make sure the row you want to delete doesn't has any child rows set with Foreign Key. In case you have , then delete the child rows first.

Also, when you click on any paging links ( here you were clicking page 2), then also `onrowcommand` is called and then you were deleting a row which doesn't makes any logic.

That's it. Once you click `delete` button in your Grid view, it will delete the row, provided you have set up the `Delete` command correctly for `SqlDataSource` control.

Just reiterating the mistakes in your code:

- With DataSourceId as `SqlDataSource` control, you need to set the `Delete` command of this datasource control.when we click delete button the GridView will accordingly pass on this to `SqlDataSource` with correct parameters
- **`onrowcommand`  should not be used to delete a row.**
- In case you want some code to be executed **after** a row is deleted, use `OnRowDeleted` event

Let me know if you need more clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

check this out, always remember u need to put this as your gridview pagination

```
 protected void grdView_PageIndexChanging(Object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    grdView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    grdView.DataSource = bindgrid();
    grdView.DataBind();  
}
```

and this is the sample code link

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/1249-Grid-View-Paging-Sorting.aspx

hope this can help u out=)

Comment: i try to follow the line u give. but once it reaches da.fill(ds) . it will prompt me : Login failed for user 'MCDU-PC34\apr13mpsip'.

Comment: the link is using SqlDataAdapter sadp , not dataset, can u try to use SqlDataAdapter ?

Comment: @PorWeiting so how is the result now? =)

Comment: i enconunter this error when i run the code to here : dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;  they say cant find my table name 0. then i change my table name to Student which is my table name then i got error there. so i not sure what is the [0] inside.

Comment: there are problem from your ConnString & StrQuery, make sure ur connection and query is correct

Comment: your errors happened is because there are no result is return from your database. so, time to check your connection and query xD

Comment: do i need to change anything inside this statement :  "GridView1.DataKeys[0].Value"

Comment: when my code run to this statement : " dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;" i will have error like : "index out of range exception was unhandled by user code. cannot find table 0" .

Comment: this is because your query return nothing , have u check your db connection and query? it is correct syntax?

Comment: i put it this way : private DataView bindgrid()
    {
        String ConnString ="Data Source=MCDU\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=n;Integrated Security=True";
        String StrQuery = "select * from Student";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(StrQuery, ConnString);

        dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        return dv;
    }

Comment: do you have student table? b4 this how to u bind ur gridview ?i assumed there are some code conflict in your pages

Comment: i do have a table name Student. i think so too. but not sure where the conflict is.

Comment: find all databind() in your pages and check =)